# open an intent from inside an Intent service

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to execute this code from an intent service

```
  public void showAlertDialog(String title, CharSequence message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    if (title != null) builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Helper.OpenFile(sharing_download.this,DownloadedFilePath + "test.pdf");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(DownloadFolderPath);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            return;
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Though i am receiving the following error :

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

I understand that the reason is because we can't open an Activity from within an intent service, though i need to trigger that function as my logic here is as the following :

1. A user download a file
2. the file is being downloaded by calling the Intent service
3. when the file end downloading and service finish i need to trigger this function and update the files list view

But i am stuck with this error now, any idea ?

Comment: Yes, you can start an `Activity` from an `IntentService`, though usually it is impolite. Your code is for an `AlertDialog`, not an `Activity`, and you cannot show an `AlertDialog` from an `IntentService`.

Comment: I want to ask the user if he want to navigate for the download folder, what should i do ? other than creating an activity and putting two buttons and call that activity

Comment: I would raise a `Notification` that leads to the activity (or has two actions corresponding to your two buttons). You do not know what the user is doing in the foreground when your `IntentService` gets to this point.

Comment: This is a good idea . Any solution for updating my listview ?? . I could not manage to update it as when the user download the file i am updating my record in the database and i need to update my listview . How can i do this ? Any idea ? Much appreciation

Comment: Use an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus) to have your service let the UI know that such-and-so data changed.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a link i can follow ?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot3

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html

if you want to send data to other components from a IntentService, use a broadcastManager to send bundled data with an Intent and enable a broadcastReceiver at the components to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use getApplication().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));

Answer (score 0):

You can not open a dialog from and intent service. to do that, you can intent to start an activity, put it in a translucent theme and show your AlertDialog.